# Movie play error

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying play a video on device. Video is this 
[video](http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.mp4)

and my code:

```
  NSString *urlStr = @"http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.mp4";
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
  moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);  
[moviePlayer play];
```

When i start app an movie screen is seen  but movie doesnt play. Can you help me where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

Try use 
    `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithPath:urlStr];`

instead of 
    `NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];`
It is a web url not a file url.

Answer (score 0):

Check this video for reference. This works for me -

```
- (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
    NSString *filepath   =   @"http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.mp4";
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                               name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                             object:moviePlayerController];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];
}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                                                object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [moviePlayerController release];
}
```

Comment: it didnt play. a screen was seen for a sec but video didnt play.which framework did you import? and how is your .h class

Comment: try this - http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mediaplayer-framework_mpmovieplayercontroller_ios4/. this has source code too.

Comment: error is this:     An instance 0x7a58230 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7a58160> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7859360: Observer: 0x7835190, Key path: nonForcedSubtitleDisplayEnabled, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x78593e0>

Comment: answer is there in the stacktrace itself.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble -- iOS5 only.  Whenever the player is deallocated, I get that AVPlayerItem leak and then a crash later.  Any help??

Comment: @GaryO @yatanadam maybe this answer will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384388/mpmovieplayercontroller-still-leaking. This seems to be related to `KeyVAlueObservation` notification.

Comment: @SrikarAppal thanks, but that question is about NotificationCenter notifications (explicitly added by the user), not KVO, which is where my problem seems to come from.  The KVO observer nonForcedSubtitleDisplayEnabled is something the OS is adding to the player, not me.  Could be a bug, could be simulator-only too -- I don't have a real iPhone running iOS5 here.  So I'm still stuck.

Comment: oh oh i know this! Are you running this in simulator? I too get this problem in simulator. This does not happen on the device...